# Sums of remainders in Euclidean GCD algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I've noticed that when going through the steps of Euclidean GCD algorithms, very often the sum of the remainders in the steps $s_{i+1}$ and $s_{i+2}$ will be equal to the remainder in step $s_i$. However, this isn't always the case.

## Example

To illustrate what I'm talking about consider this:

$$
gcd(612,93):\\
\begin{align*}
s_1: 612 &= 6 \times 93 + 54 \\
s_2: 93 &= 1 \times 54 + 39 \\
s_3: 54 &= 1 \times 39 + 15 \\
s_4: 39 &= 2 \times 15 + 9 \\
s_5: 15 &= 1 \times 9 + 6 \\
s_6: 9 &= 1 \times 6 + 3 \\
s_7: 6 &= 2 \times 3 + 0
\end{align*}
$$

Notice how $54=39+15$, $15=9+6$, $9=3+6$, but $39 \neq 15+9$.

## Question

Is there any reason for this to happen? How to tell if the remainder will not be the sum of the remainders in two subsequent steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that this happens when you get a $1$ for a quotient. For example, it's right there in the lines $54=1\times 39+15,\, 15=1\times 9+6,\,9=1\times 6+3$. If you think of $93$ as the first remainder, then $93=1\times 54+39$.

Then the question is "why do you so often get a quotient of $1$?" This is a result of random processes. If the remainder after division: $a=bq+r$, is roughly random between $0$ and $b-1$, then the next term $b=rq_2+r_2$ will have quotient $q_2=1$ roughly 1/2 of the time - whenever $2r>b$.

Comment: It's a bit late over here, so I'm not up to doing the sums right now. But I have a feeling that your "roughly 1/2" will turn out to be $1/\varphi$ in the limit.

Comment: My underlying reason for asking this question was to figure out whether I can substitute division (or modulo) with subtraction. (I know that from CS perspective there are more efficient GCD algorithms, still having the "classical" one being reformulated would be nice. I see now, that if I after computing the modulo just once, I'd keep subtracting, I'd still get the same result (albeit in more steps). Though I'm not really able to prove it to myself. Would you care to comment on this? Intuitively, when I think about this as cutting remainder from a rectangle it seems to make sense.

Comment: According to brief research, the actual limit is $2-\log_2 3\approx 0.415$ - that is the (limit of) the probability that the $n$th coefficient of a continued fraction is $1$. @TonyK

Comment: @wvxvw: I wouldn't recommend that approach. The problem is, it has a terrible worst-case behaviour (specifically, if one of the arguments is much smaller than the other).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, you were right: the probability that the quotient is $q$ is the same as the probability that a continued-fraction coefficient is $q$, which is $\log_2((q+1)^2/(q^2+2q))$. Empirical evidence support this.